# Solve PDE with complicated coefficient non-linearity

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear, event-detection, coefficients

I wish to solve is the heat equation with solution-dependent coefficient.
The equation along with BC's and IC's are as follows:
$\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial P[x,t]}{\partial t}-\alpha[x,t]\frac{\partial^2 P[x,t]}{\partial x^2}=0
\end{equation}$,
$\begin{equation}P[x,0]=0,P[L,t]=0
\end{equation}$,
$P[0,t]=Step[t-t1]-0.5Step[t-t2]-0.25Step[t-t3]$,
 $L=1$.
The $\alpha[x,t]$ coeffiecnt is determined by the following rules:
$\alpha[x,0]=\alpha_1$,
If $P[x,t]>0.7$ $\rightarrow$ Set $\alpha[x,t]$ to $\alpha_2$
If $P[x,t]<0.3$ $\rightarrow$ Set $\alpha[x,t]$ to $\alpha_1$
If $0.3<P[x,t]<0.7$ $\rightarrow$ Do Nothing.

Those conditions represent the case of bistability of the diffusion coefficient.

I've tried quite a few methods to solve it, including the definition of $\alpha$ as a function of $\frac{\partial P[x,t]}{\partial t}$ and $P[x,t]$ with a combination of `Sing[]`,`Boole[]`,`WhenEvent[]`,ect.

None of them worked at the past few weeks, so any idea may help.
Thanks,
Ofek.

Comment: If the thermal conductivity is variable, don't you need to express the heat equation as $\rho {{\hat C}_p}(u)\frac{{\partial u}}{{\partial t}} + \nabla  \cdot \left( { - k(u)\nabla u} \right) = 0$?

Comment: Yes, the case I've mentioned is a simplified version of the full equation (as you wrote)

Comment: In the last application of the [WhenEvent Documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhenEvent.html), they have an example of an ON/OFF controller (which is a bistable system with hysteresis) applied to the 2D heat equation.  Did you try to adapt that example?

Comment: @OfekPeretz Can you provide data for a numerical model?

Comment: It is effectively impossible to diagnose what has gone wrong if the actual code used is not posted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the OP is trying to demonstrate hysteresis. WhenEvent has an example of an on-off controller, which is an example of a bistable system. Unfortunately, my understanding is, that an event must be a function of time only and cannot have local spatial dependence.  The essence of the Numerical Method of Lines is to turn a time-dependent PDE into a system of ODEs depending on time only.  This suggests that perhaps we can combine WhenEvent with a roll your own version of the Numerical Method Of Lines. To build this model, it is best to start simple so let us start with a zero dimensional case that demonstrates hysteresis with WhenEvent.

### 0-D Case

Let us consider a small system with no diffusion limitations driven by a fluctuating heat source. The ODE that we wish to solve is given by:

$${\hat C_p}(u)\frac{du}{dt} = q\left( t \right)$$

We will start with a system that is initially solid.  We will set up a simple test case to verify that our WhenEvent construction gives us the correct bistable behavior.

```
cpl = 2;
cps = 1;
thresholdliquid = Rationalize[0.7];
thresholdsolid = Rationalize[0.3];
q[t] = 5/2 UnitStep[-7 + t] - 5/2 UnitStep[-6 + t] + 
   5/2 UnitStep[-5 + t] - 5/2 UnitStep[-3 + t] + UnitStep[-1 + t];
NDSolve[{cp[t] u'[t] == q[t], cp[0] == cps, u[0] == 0, 
   WhenEvent[{u[t] == thresholdliquid, 
     u[t] == thresholdsolid} , {cp[t] -> 
      If[u[t] == thresholdliquid, cpl, 
       If[u[t] == thresholdsolid, cps, cp[t]]]}]}, {u, cp}, {t, 0, 
   10}, DiscreteVariables -> {cp \[Element] {cps, cpl}}  ];
Plot[{Evaluate[{u[t], cp[t] - cps} /. %], thresholdsolid, 
  thresholdliquid}, {t, 0, 10}, PlotTheme -> "Web", 
 PlotStyle -> {Thick, Thick, Dashed, Dashed}]
```

[image: Bistable 0D case]

You can clearly see breaks in the temperature curve that have different thresholds if the temperature is rising or falling. So, it looks as though we have a good prototype for bistability using WhenEvent in the 0D case.

### Combining WhenEvent with a Roll-Your-Own Numerical Method of Lines

In the Boundary Conditions section of [The Numerical Method Of Lines Tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html), Shows how you can roll your own numerical method of lines schemes to convert a PDE into a system of ODEs.  The following Mathematica code attempts to combine our WhenEvent prototype with the procedure outlined in the numerical method of lines tutorial.  I used arbitrary values for the parameters since none were supplied. The thermal diffusivity difference between ice and water is about a factor of 9. However, an ice water system would have such a large latent heat effects that you would need to use the form of the equation I alluded to in the comments.

```
(* Set Parameters *)
n = 50; Subscript[h, n] = 
 1/n; sf = 1; tmax = 10; alphasolid = 1; alphaliquid = 1/10*alphasolid;
t1 = 1; t2 = 4; t3 = 5 ;
thresholdliquid = Rationalize[0.7];
thresholdsolid = Rationalize[0.3];
(* Create Temperature and Phase State Vector *)
U[t_] = Table[Subscript[u, i][t], {i, 0, n}];
A[t_] = Table[Subscript[a, i][t], {i, 0, n}];
dvbls = Head[#] & /@ A[t];
(* Differentiate BCs *)
bc0 = Subscript[u, 0][t] == 
   UnitStep[t - t1] - 1/2*UnitStep[t - t2] - 1/4*UnitStep[t - t3];
bc0d = Map[D[#, t] + sf # &, bc0];
bc1 = Subscript[u, n][t] == 0;
bc1d = Map[D[#, t] + sf # &, bc1];
(* Set Laplacian *)
laplacianu = 
  NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[2, Subscript[h, n] Range[0, n], 
   U[t]];
(* Set up system of ODEs *)
eqns = Thread[D[U[t], t] -  A[t] laplacianu == 0];
(* Replace Boundary Condtions Equations *)
eqns[[1]] = bc0d;
eqns[[-1]] = bc1d;
(* Set Initial Temperature to 0 *)
ics = Thread[U[0] == Table[0, {n + 1}]];
(* Set Initial Phase State to Solid *)
istates = Thread[A[0] == Table[alphasolid, {n + 1}]];
(* Set up Events*)
events = WhenEvent[{Subscript[u, #][t] == tl, 
       Subscript[u, #][t] == ts} , {Subscript[a, #][t] -> 
        If[Subscript[u, #][t] == tl, alphaliquid, 
         If[Subscript[u, #][t] == ts, alphasolid, 
          Subscript[a, #][t]]]}] & /@ 
    Range[0, n] /. {ts -> thresholdsolid, tl -> thresholdliquid};
(* Join System of Equations to be Solved *)
system = Join[eqns, ics, istates, events];
lines = NDSolve[system, Join[U[t], A[t]], {t, 0, tmax}, 
   DiscreteVariables -> dvbls];
(* Create Interpolation Functions for Easier Plotting *)
f = Interpolation[
   Flatten[Table[{{t, i Subscript[h, n]}, 
      First[Subscript[u, i][t] /. lines]}, {i, 0, n}, {t, 0, tmax, 
      tmax/500}], 1], InterpolationOrder -> 2];
fa = Interpolation[
   Flatten[Table[{{t, i Subscript[h, n]}, 
      First[Subscript[a, i][t] /. lines]}, {i, 0, n}, {t, 0, tmax, 
      tmax/500}], 1], InterpolationOrder -> 2];
(* Plot Temperature and Diffusivity *)
ContourPlot[f[t, x], {t, 0.`, tmax}, {x, 0.`, 1}, 
 PlotPoints -> {200, 200}, MaxRecursion -> 4, PlotTheme -> "Web", 
 ColorFunction -> ColorData["DarkBands"]]
ContourPlot[fa[t, x], {t, 0.`, tmax}, {x, 0.`, 1}, 
 PlotPoints -> {200, 200}, MaxRecursion -> 4, PlotTheme -> "Web", 
 ColorFunction -> ColorData["DarkBands"]]
```

#### Temperature Contour Plot

[image: Bistable Temperature Plot]

#### Diffusivity State Contour Plot

[image: Bistable Diffusivity Plot]

#### Demonstration of Bistability

We should be able to demonstrate bistability by plotting the temperature and the diffusivity at a value that intersects the phase envelope (e.g., $x=0.1$) as shown with the following Mathematica code.

```
Plot[{f[t, 0.1], fa[t, 0.1], thresholdsolid, thresholdliquid}, {t, 0, 
  10}, PlotTheme -> "Web", 
 PlotStyle -> {Thick, Thick, Dashed, Dashed}]
```

[image: Bistable MOL]

The system behaves as expected showing transitions at 0.7 going up and 0.3 going down.  One can use ParametricPlot to demonstrate the path dependence more clearly as shown below.

```
p0 = ParametricPlot[{f[t, 0.1], fa[t, 0.1]}, {t, 0, 10}, 
   ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][#3] &), MaxRecursion -> 0, 
   PlotPoints -> 100, PlotTheme -> "Web"];
p0 /. l_Line :> {Arrowheads[ConstantArray[0.05, 30]], Arrow[l]}
```

[image: Hysteresis Plot]

### Update To Include No Flux Condition at x=1

In the comments, Ofek requested to also consider the case of a no flux condition at $x$=$1$.  It turns out that the [MOL Tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html) actually considers this very case.  One just needs to adjust bc1 and bc1d accordingly

```
bc1 = Last[
    NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[1, Subscript[h, n] Range[0, n],
      U[t]]] == 0;
bc1d = Map[D[#, t] &, bc1];
```

Note that the scale factor $sf$ has been set to zero for Neumann type conditions.  Without adjustments to the first case, you will obtain plots for temperature and diffusivity state as shown below:

#### Temperature Contour Plot No Flux on End

[image: Temperature No Flux Case]

#### Diffusivity State Contour Plot No Flux on End

[image: Diffusivity No Flux Case]

You will have to adjust parameters to make the plots look more interesting.

Comment: a very good example in MMA!

Comment: @TimLaska, Thanks for your detailed solution, this is exactly what I wanted to solve. Just one more question - How can I change the boundary condition at $X=1$ from $P_n(0)==0$ into $\frac{\partial P_n(0)}{\partial x}==0$?

Comment: @OfekPeretz  I added a no flux case to the post.

Comment: @TimLaska, Amazing. Thanks!

Comment: @OfekPeretz, You are welcome!

Comment: @TimLaska , why I have the following error:NDSolve::dsvar: 0.5` cannot be used as a variable.

Comment: @ABCDEMMM, Looking at the second example of this link for [dsvar error](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/DSolve/dsvar.html), it seems like you might need to Clear a variable or variables or perhaps close out and start a new session.

Comment: @TimLaska , this problem is solved, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I do not see what the problem is.

```
t1 = 1; t2 = 2; t3 = 3; L = 10; T = 10;
bc = {P[t, 0] == 0, 
   P[t, L] == 
    UnitStep[t - t1] - UnitStep[t - t2]/2 - UnitStep[t - t3]/4};
a[p_] := Piecewise[{{1, p < .3}, {2, .3 <= p < .5}, {1/2, True}}]
ic = {P[0, x] == 0};
eq = D[P[t, x], t] - a[P[t, x]]*D[P[t, x], x, x] == 0;
sol = NDSolveValue[{eq, ic, bc}, P, {t, 0, T}, {x, 0, L}];
{ContourPlot[sol[t, x], {t, 0, T}, {x, 0, L}, Contours -> 20, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, 
  FrameLabel -> {"t", "x"}], 
 ContourPlot[sol[t, x], {t, 0, 5}, {x, L - 2, L}, Contours -> 20, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, 
  FrameLabel -> {"t", "x"}]}
```

[image: fig1]