# Trouble in a delay ordinary differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, integral-equations

I have a delayed partial differential equation to be solved because MMA cannot solve directly. I just used the method of this post [Solve PDE with complicated coefficient non-linearity](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/188872/solve-pde-with-complicated-coefficient-non-linearity/188942#188942) to transform it into a system of delayed ordinary differential equations. However, when trying to solve the system of delay ordinary differential equations, I encountered an error reported by the program. It says that integral variables are not real numbers.
This is the equation I tried.
$$v\left( t \right) -w\left( t \right) -v''\left( t \right) =0$$
$$v (t) + 2 w (t) + w'' (t)-\exp (-\eta t)\int_ 0^t\exp (x) w (x)\, \mathrm dx = \exp (t)$$
The equations is a ordinary differential equations with delay integral, which I got arbitrarily. The key point of the equations have an integral function. Their initial condition is 0.
Here is the code I tried.

```
ode = {v[t] - w[t] - Derivative[2][v][t] == 0, v[t] + 2*w[t] + Derivative[2][w][t] - Exp[-\[Eta]t]*Integrate[Exp[x]*w[x], {x, 0, t}] == Exp[t]}; 
ics = {v[0] == 0, Derivative[1][v][0] == 0, w[0] == 0, Derivative[1][w][0] == 0}; 
rs = Apply[Set, Flatten[NDSolve[{ode, ics}, {v, w}, {t, 0, 5}]], {1}]
```

Here is the result I got, which says $x$ isn't a real number. HELP!
[image]

Comment: Why do you add `Set@@@` in your code? What are you trying to achieve with this? Also, it's not hard to notice the solution to the system is `w[t]==v[t]==0`, if it should not, something is probably wrong with the system, please double check it.

Comment: Adding $v (t) + 2 w (t) + w'' (t)-\exp (-t)\int_ 0^t\exp (x) w (x)\, dx = 0$ with it's derivative results in $v(t)+w(t)+v'(t)+2w'(t)+w''(t)+w'''(t)=0$.

Comment: Use set@@@ to directly assign values to the obtained rule list. Yes, I provided an oversimplified version of the original equation, leaving out the external load input.

Comment: Then it's not a good idea to add `Set@@@` before you've successfully resolved the equation.

Comment: You're right, I've learned.*.= Thanks a lot.

Comment: If η is added to the coefficient of exponential function before integral function, it cannot be eliminated by derivative superposition.

Answer (score 5):

The problem can be solved analytically with `LaplaceTransform`:

```
tode = LaplaceTransform[ode, t, s] /. Rule @@@ ics

tsol = Solve[tode, LaplaceTransform[{v[t], w[t]}, t, s]][[1, All, -1]]

{exprv, exprw} = InverseLaplaceTransform[tsol, s, t] // Simplify;

Plot[{exprv, exprw}, {t, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that the problem can't solve it directly using NDSovle.

Comment: That's it! (1 upvote.)